# Simplifying the following computation of $n$-form

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I'm trying to show $n-1$-form
$$
\iota_{S^{n-1}}^*(\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}x^idx^1\wedge \cdots \widehat{dx^i}\wedge \cdots dx^n)
$$
is a nowhere vanishing differential form on $S^{n-1}$. For the case $n = 2,3$, using the coordinate representation $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $(r\cos\varphi_1,r\sin\varphi_1\cos\varphi_2,r\sin\varphi_1\sin\varphi_2)$, after the painful computation, I got $d\theta$ for the first case and $\sin\varphi_1 d\varphi_1\wedge d\varphi_2$ for the second one. I suspect that only the term that does not contains $dr$ in the differential form survives. But I don't want to do this for general $n$. I believe there is a simpler way to show the above $n-1$ form on $S^{n-1}$ is nowhere vanishing differential form. Is there any way to show that? Is my method the simplest?

Note. I'm following the notation of spherical coordinate representation of $S^{n-1}$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) "spherical coordinate" section.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a simpler way. Stay in cartesian coordinates!

Note that if we consider the radial  vector field $X=\sum x^i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, then your $(n-1)$-form can be written as (the restriction to the sphere of) $\iota_X (dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n)$. The last piece of the puzzle is ... what geometric relation does $X$ have to $S^{n-1}$ at the point $x\in S^{n-1}$?

Comment: You mean the normal vector field?

Comment: Yes, precisely. So what do you get when you evaluate on an orthonormal basis for $T_xS^{n-1}$?

Comment: Only one of those makes sense.

Comment: Orthonormal basis for the tangent space of the sphere? Are you using the definition of $\iota_X$?

Comment: As far as I understood, $\iota_X(dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^n)(v_1,...,v_{n-1}) = (dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^n)(X,v_1,...,v_{n-1})$ where $v_i$ are orthonomal basis of $T_xS^{n-1}$. Letting $v_0 = X$, $=\det(dx^j(v_i))$. Correct so far?

Comment: Yes. This is precisely correct.

Comment: I can see that the first row of matrix $(dx^j(v_i))$ is just $(x^1\ \cdots\ x^n)$. How can I treat those orthonomal basis $v_i$'s ?

Comment: You don't care about the first row. You care only that the $n$ vectors form an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Have you seen the last step? It is the definition underlying differential forms.